Which comma(s) can I remove in this sentence? I feel like there are too many here but all seem necessary to me

We can see that the London subway system, which was opened in 1863, has the longest total track length, at 394 kilometers, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo, at 199 and 155 kilometers respectively.

Which comma(s) can I remove in this sentence? I feel like there are too many here but all seem necessary to me. What would you do in this situation?

What are you supposing those refers to?

You can remove "which was", but otherwise I see no problems with commas here. See however the previous comment regarding "those".

I think the reason this sentence looks awkward is not because there are too many commas for the number of clauses, but because there are too many clauses in one sentence.
The core of the sentence is this:

We can see that the London subway system has the longest total track length, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo.

There are then three different parenthetical clauses:

which was opened in 1863
at 394 kilometers
at 199 and 155 kilometers respectively

This makes the sentence hard to follow - the reader has to track that "those" refers back to "subway system[s]", and "at" refers to "total track length".
There are a few different ways the sentence can be split in two, reducing this awkwardness; for instance:

We can see that the London subway system, which was opened in 1863, has the longest total track length, at 394 kilometers. The next longest systems are in Paris and Tokyo, with 199 and 155 kilometers of track respectively.

or:

We can see that the London subway system, which was opened in 1863, has the longest total track length, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo. The London system has a total length of 394 kilometers, Paris 199 kilometers, and Tokyo 155 kilometers.

or perhaps (adding some information so that the year stands as a fact on its own):

We can see that the London subway system has the longest total track length, at 394 kilometers, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo, at 199 and 155 kilometers respectively. The London system is also the oldest, having opened in 1863.


This. Trying to fix it with commas is a waste of time. There's too much going on in one sentence.

Note that the final example has slightly different meaning.  It tells the reader that the London subway system is the oldest.  Mind you, providing this information avoids awkwardness, since without it a reader would wonder why the year was provided for London but not Paris and Tokyo.

@Brian Yes, I felt "The London system opened in 1863" would have been an odd sentence on its own, so added some context; I have made an edit to make that more explicit.

Since as you noted those are parenthetical clauses, another option is to put them into parentheses rather than commas -- or perhaps only change some of them, if the goal is to have more variety.

@Miral The goal is certainly not "more variety"; it is to help the reader follow the meaning of the sentence. Parentheses rather than commas can help a bit with that, if some information is truly "optional", because they make it clearer where the "main" information is. If the publishing context supports it, you could even move such additional facts to footnotes. However, my impression in this case is that the detailed facts are actually important to the writing, so I'm suggesting making them less parenthetical.

I would remove the commas before the two "at", they are unnecessary, and add one before "respectively":

We can see that the London subway system, which was opened in 1863, has the longest total track length at 394 kilometers, followed by those in Paris and Tokyo at 199 and 155 kilometers, respectively.


Really?  Agreed that removing the commas before the ats is good, but once they’re removed, the comma before respectively sounds quite wrong, to my ear.  Both in terms of the logical structure of the sentence, and of its natural rhythm when spoken, the break before respectively feels strictly subordinate to the break before the second at.

@PLL The rule in Britsh English is to write this phrase without a comma before respectively, the rule for American English is to write this phrase with a comma before respectively.

Interesting; I hadn’t come across that American rule.  Where do you get it from?  My go-to for American conventions is the CMoS, which doesn’t mandate commas for most uses of respectively, as quoted and discussed for example here.

@PLL For example here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectively (the first example is BE, the second, under "American Dictionary", is AE). —— The CMOS contains 20 examples for respectively, all with a comma. Your linked answer misunderstands the cited rule. The CMOS writes: "At the end of a sentence, a comma is necessary only when the phrase is used in a nonrestrictive sense, providing information that is not essential to the meaning of the rest of the sentence." Example from CMOS: "Henrietta turned fifty in 1931. but Henrietta turned fifty a decade later, in 1931."

I would also suggest a more thorough re-write. For example, something like:

We can see that the London subway system, which was opened in 1863, has the longest total track length (394km), followed by those of Paris (199km) and Tokyo (155km).

You were using the commas to offset parenthetical statements, and that's precisely what parentheses are for. You could also use em dashes, yet a third way of writing parenthetical statements:

We can see that the London subway system—which was opened in 1863—has the longest total track length (394km), followed by those of Paris (199km) and Tokyo (155km).

You can also change the structure around:

Opened in 1863, and with a total length of 394km, the London subway system is the longest in the world, followed by those of Paris (199km) and Tokyo (155km).

